# Get the post URL from wordpress posts

Tags: multisite, permalinks

I am not able to get the actual wordpress URL from the blogs in my multisite wordpress

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'network_id' => $wpdb->siteid,
    'public'     => null,
    'archived'   => null,
    'mature'     => null,
    'spam'       => null,
    'deleted'    => null,
    'limit'      => 100,
    'offset'     => 0,
); 
$all_blogs = wp_get_sites($args);

foreach($all_blogs as $all_blog){
    $blogID =  $all_blog['blog_id'];
    $blog_name = $all_blog['path'];

    global $wpdb;

    $prefix =  $wpdb->prefix.$blogID ;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$prefix."_posts where post_status = 'publish'");

        foreach($results as $result){
            $Post_url = get_permalink($result->ID, false);
            $guid_URL = $result->guid;
         }
}
```

?>

Here i am looping through all the blogs and posts to fetch the URL

For example GUID URL looks like this

```
http://ww.example.com/?p=180
```

when i run this URL in my browser my URL changes to this

```
http://www.example.com/abc/xyz
```

So now how do i get the actual URL in wordpress?

Comment: what do you get if you echo `$Post_url` instead of `$guid_URL`?

Comment: since i am looping through the complete blogs i am getting http://www.example.com/blog/

Comment: you might find it's easier to make use of the `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` functions : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog